# Unresponsive Keys in Interactive CV2 Python Session on OSX terminal

Tags: python, macos, opencv, homebrew

Installed opencv with homebrew (`brew install opencv`) and running some of the [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) sample scripts that came as part of it's [library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/).

The scripts seem to run without complaint, however the keyboard input seems to be non-responsive. The letter keys just put the letter typed into the terminal window and esc yields `^[`.

Some [arbitrary-seeming google results](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/665) are hinting that this issue *could* be because python is not running as a system framework, but I have tried running the scripts via `python` and `python2.7` with the same result and those executables are outlined below:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root        wheel     58608 Oct 28 09:34 python
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root        wheel       925 Mar 10  2014 python-config
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root        wheel       925 Oct 23 14:48 python-config-backup
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root        wheel        75 Oct 28 09:34 python2.5 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python2.5
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root        wheel        82 Oct 28 09:34 python2.5-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python2.5-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root        wheel        75 Oct 28 09:34 python2.6 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root        wheel        82 Oct 28 09:34 python2.6-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root        wheel        75 Oct 28 09:34 python2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root        wheel        82 Oct 28 09:34 python2.7-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root        wheel     58608 Oct 28 09:34 pythonw
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root        wheel        76 Oct 28 09:34 pythonw2.5 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/pythonw2.5
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root        wheel        76 Oct 28 09:34 pythonw2.6 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/pythonw2.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root        wheel        76 Oct 28 09:34 pythonw2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7
```

I don't actually remember how the python executables that reside directly within `/usr/bin/python` got there (having tried a good many installs (fink, python gui, homebrew) and configurations when unsuccessfully attempting to configure psql/python/psycopg2).

Might this issue have to do with needing to add something to the (empty) PYTHONPATH? Is it what's called a binding that `homebrew` installed at `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.py` and does that need to be linked, copied or moved to one of the python versions I have installed?

Within `cd /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/` I added two symlinks:

```
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel     64 Dec 24 19:21 cv.py -> /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.py
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel     65 Dec 24 19:21 cv2.so -> /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
```

I don't relish the idea of having to install python with `homebrew`, but am open to it.

Comment: probably obvious, but in the `cli` using python2.7, the sys.executable is `'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python'` and under `python` it's `'usr/bin/python'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah. So simple (of course). The OpenCV `window` and the `buttons` (assigned to `waitKey`) are interdependent, so `waitKey` only captures input when an OpenCV window has focus.

Thanks to the PACKT publishing **OpenCV Computer Vision with Python** book for the clue. Of course `R`ing`TFM` would have probably done the trick quite handily as well.